# MongoDB & Redis cache

Tags: mongodb, caching, optimization, redis

I'm currently using MongoDB and Redis cache to make my backend faster & performant.

For example, I have a query that gets all blog posts for a specific category. The query get caches and Redis return the response much faster:

```
{
  id: "",
  name: "",
  shortDescription: "",
  createdAt: ""
}
```

The problem is that for the requesting user, I also want to pass a "hasRead" key so that the frontend know if the blog post is new or not for the connected user:

```
{
  id: "",
  name: "",
  shortDescription: "",
  createdAt: "",
  hasRead: false
}
```

So I'm currently trying to know which would be the better way to achieve this while keeping the advantage of Redis cache.

Any best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Do you mean you want to mark it in Redis?

Comment: @GuyKorland, I mean that I'm not sure about the right strategy to keep the query in Redis cache. Apart from the "hasRead" param, everything else won't really change for users. So I'm wondering if I'll need to do it using 2 queries and merge them together

Comment: Sorry I'm not really getting your question, if the question is should you update the same key or create another key, I guess it depends how complex is the first key and how much work will it require from you. If that is the case you might want to check https://redisjson.io